# Real time sync (magento2 - vue-storefront)

Tags: magento, synchronization, vue-storefront

I'm working on a `vue-storefront` project integrated with magento-2 Backend and it's new tech that I just started working with.

The problem is that the `vue-storefront` is not well documented.  My supervisors helped me deploy the magento backend and it's already integrated with the vue-storefront-api/vue storefront, but it always needs to pump the data every time when adding products or categories in the magento backend.

How can I do realtime data sync from the magento api backend with the `vue-storefront` api?

Answer (score 0):

To get realtime data sync (or almost realtime with CRON tab for bigger sites) - you should use Magento2 VSBridge Indexer plugin for Magento 2. It connects directly with VSF-API's Elasticsearch and updates data there just after something is being changed in the Magento2. You could find the whole documentation about the module in the readme: https://github.com/DivanteLtd/magento2-vsbridge-indexer